# Check if video is playing using Serenity BDD and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to verify if a video is playing when the user clicks on the play button. Is there a way to find if the video is playing, like make sure the timeline is not at "0" etc?

Please find my code below

The Page object:

```
public class VideoPage {

    private static final String VIDEO_ELEMENT = "//*[@id='examplevideo_html5_api']";

    public String findTitle() {
        return getText(ABOUT_MODAL_TITLE);
    }

    private void videoIsPlaying() {
        // ????
    }
}
```

The Test code:

```
@When("user clicks on Play button on the modal")
public void userClicksOnPlayButton() {
    aboutUsUser.clickPlayButtonModal();
}

@Then("the video should start playing")
public void videoShouldPlay() {
    videoUser.showPauseButton();
    videoUser.videoIsPlaying();
    Object t = videoUser.videoElement().getAttribute("currentTime");
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have such test for some similar page. Maybe the details will be different here, but the idea I used is:

1. Play the video
2. Get video current time
3. Set some pause
4. Get video current time again
5. Validate that the initial video current time and the second current time values are not the same.
   Here is my code:

```java
public class Reusable extends BasePage {
    public Reusable(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    //Embedded YouTube elements
    public String videoIframe = "//iframe[@class='elementor-video']";
    public String playVideoBtn = "//button[@aria-label ='Play']";
    public String videoCurrentTimeIndicator = "//span[@class='ytp-time-current']";
    public String muteYoutubeBtn = "//button[contains(@class,'mute-button')]";

    //Embedded YouTube methods
    public void switchToVideoIframe(){
        switchToIframe(videoIframe);
    }

    public void playVideo(){
        clickVisible(playVideoBtn);
    }

    public String getVideoCurrentTime(){
        return getVisibleElementText(videoCurrentTimeIndicator);
    }

    public boolean validateVideoIsPlaying(){
        playVideo();
        String initialVideoTime = getVideoCurrentTime();
        wait(3000);
        hoverOverElement(muteYoutubeBtn);
        String secondVideoTime = getVideoCurrentTime();
        Assert.assertFalse(initialVideoTime.contains(secondVideoTime),"Failed playing the embedded YouTube video");
    }
}
```

The methods inside the Basepage are used here are:

```java
public void switchToIframe(By locator){
    waitForElementPresence(locator);
    wait(100);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(locator));
}

public void switchToIframe(String xpath){
    switchToIframe(By.xpath(xpath));
}


public void clickVisible(By element){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
    driver.findElement(element).click();
}

public void clickVisible(String xpath){
    clickVisible(By.xpath(xpath));
}

public String getVisibleElementText(By element){
    waitForElementToBeVisible(element);
    wait(50);
    return driver.findElement(element).getText();
}

public String getVisibleElementText(String xpath){
    return getVisibleElementText(By.xpath(xpath));
}

public void hoverOverElement(By element){
    action = new Actions(driver);
    webElement = driver.findElement(element);
    action.moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();
}

public void hoverOverElement(String xpath){
    hoverOverElement(By.xpath(xpath));
}

public void wait(int delay){
    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly((long) delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is Chrome, there is a Promise returned. Simply get that promise may be via JS executor to get true as value. JS code :-

```
var playPromise = document.querySelector('video').play();
```

See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise

similarly there should be something for other browsers as well(Could be the same promise working for all)

Also see:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs